# Spring Actuator - How to exclude HealthEndpoint from autowiring in test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testng, spring-test

I am trying to run a test but I got an exception when I try to run it `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint' available:`

I have two packages `com.test.data` and `com.test.health` in my main folder. My main `Application` class is in `com.test.data`. In `com.test.health` I have one class with name `StartupHousekeeper implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>` and autowired `HealthEndpoint` there as below

```
@Component
public class StartupHousekeeper implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    @Autowired
    private HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;
}
```

In test I have `ControllerIntegrationTest` which is config class and code is below. Even though I did not add `com.test.health package` it is still throwing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

```
@Profile("controller-integration-test")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.data"})
@Configuration
public class ControllerIntegrationTest {
}
```

My actual test class is below

```
@TestExecutionListeners(MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"controller-integration-test"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ControllerIntegrationTest.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = AdminUserController.class, secure = false, excludeAutoConfiguration = {HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, FlywayAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AdminUserControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests implements TestConstants {}
```

When I try to run it `org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests#springTestContextPrepareTestInstance` failed to run due to above mentioned exception

[image]

Comment: As you have the added the HealthEndpoint  Bean in StartupHousekeeper Spring will try to autowire the bean. Either create a mocked Bean of HealthEndpoint or even mock StartupHousekeeper

Comment: But I have excluded the package in `ControllerIntegrationTest `

Comment: Yeah, and that is why you get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException... Look at EndpointAutoConfiguration.java there you will see that a HealthEndpoint bean would have been registered if autoconfiguration was enabled.

Comment: I enable auto configuration and it still gives error. The error occur due to autowiring of HealthEndpoint in StartHouseKeeper class . I am unable to understand why it is trying to auto wire it as I have excluded it from componentscan